# The point (4,1) undergoes the following transformations

Tags: analytic-geometry

> 1) Reflection about x=y
>
> 2)Transformation through a distance 2 units along +ve x axis
>
> 3) Rotation through an angle $\pi/4$ about the origin in the counterclockwise direction
>
> Find the final coordinates

The point becomes (1,4)

Then after shifting origin 
$$X=x-h$$
$$X=-1$$
So (-1,4)

After rotating the axes 
$$X=x\cos \pi/4+y\sin \pi/4$$
$$X=\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2} +\frac{4}{\sqrt 2}$$
$$X=\frac{3}{\sqrt 2}$$
But the x coordinate given in the answer is $\frac{-1}{\sqrt 2}$. What’s wrong?

Comment: "Transformation through a distance 2 units along +ve x axis" - if the transformation is right (i.e. not left) by 2 units, then (1,4) -> (3,4), which does not end up as (1,4) when rotated pi/4 counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is by complex numbers
$$ $$
Let $Z_1$=(3+i4) is rotated about origin by π/4 and complex number after rotation is $Z_2$
$$\frac{Z_2}{Z_1}=e^{\frac{iπ}{4}}$$
$$Z_2=(3+i4)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$
$$Z_2=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{7}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Hence point after rotation is $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{7}{\sqrt{2}})$.
For more on rotation of complex numbers check this link
https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/best-iitjee-maths-for-mains-and-advance/

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 transformation by 2 unit along +X axis point after this is (3,4)
$$ $$
Now rotation by π/4
$$ X=5(\frac{3}{5}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{4}{5}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$
$$X=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: I wrongly assumed that the origin was shifted by two units. My bad

Comment: Where did $\frac 35$ and $\frac 45$ come from?

Comment: If you join point (3,4) to origin and using parametric coordinate on the line segment after rotation total angle after rotation is ($\alpha$+π/4) where $\alpha$ is inclination of line joining (3,4) to origin.

Comment: So in case of rotation, are we rotating the axes or simply the point about an angle $\pi/4$?

Comment: Rotating point about origin by π/4

Comment: But then can we use the rotation of axes formula conversely for the Same result? I am asking because I can’t understand what you have solved

Comment: Geometrically it is similar to the one solution given by complex number.